# Sorting by alternating number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is the data table.

[image]

and I need output as following.
Logic: Sort by Date (Asc) but if 2 consecutive rows have the same 'Flag' Value (0 or 1) then alter the sorting by taking the next alternate flag. "Flag" column must be alternative 0,1,0,1 (except last row)

**Required Result:**

[image]

```
drop table if exists #A

CREATE TABLE #A(ID float, RDate date, flag int )
insert into #A values

(1,'2014-06-29',0),
(2,'2014-08-17',1),
(3,'2015-01-22',0),
(4,'2015-03-03',0),
(5,'2016-05-19',1),
(6,'2018-09-25',0),
(7,'2018-10-14',1),
(8,'2019-01-03',0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the number for each `Flag`, and then order by that:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT A.ID,
           A.RDate,
           A.flag,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.flag ORDER BY A.Rdate) AS RN
    FROM #A A)
SELECT C.ID,
       C.RDate,
       C.flag
FROM CTE C
ORDER BY C.RN,
         C.flag;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alternate the flags, use `row_number()` in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by flag order by rdate asc),
         flag;
```

This enumerates the rows separately for each `flag` value by date.  So the earliest row with flag = 0 and with flag = 1 both have an enumeration of "1".  These are then ordered by `flag` to get 0/1 -- at least up to the limit in the number of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,RDate,flag from
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()  over( order by ID) rwno from #A where flag=0
union all 
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over( order by ID) rwno from #A where flag=1
)as a
order by rwno,flag
```

Please check above Query [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyr9k.png)

Comment: No need for 2 scans of `#A` here. A partition clause enables the separate numbering.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from #A
order by DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY RDate ASC), flag;
```

Comment: I strongly recommend amending this post. While this code may answer the question (and I'm quite sure it does, given your reputation :) ), providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.